# Trying and failing to CryptProtectMemory / CryptUnprotectMemory in Delphi xe10

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have tried the following code (and varients) without any sucess, nor can I find any examples of how to call these Windows Functions from Delphi out there. Any clues would be very gratefully received.

The CryptProtectMemory does appear to produce some possibly encrypted result, but the unprotect does not change that result at all.I suspect I have done something charactisticly stupid, but I havent found it all day...

```
function WinMemEnc(PlnTxt: String): String;
var
  Enc: Pointer;
  j: Integer;
  EncSze: Cardinal;
  ws: String;
const
  CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS: Cardinal = 0;
  EncryptionBlockSize: Integer = 8;
begin
  if Length(PlnTxt) mod EncryptionBlockSize = 0 then
    j := Length(PlnTxt)
  else
    j := ((Length(PlnTxt) div 8) + 1) * 8;
    ws := StringofChar(' ', j);
    Move(PlnTxt[1], ws[1], j);
    Enc := Pointer(ws);
  EncSze := j * 2;
  if CryptProtectMemory(Enc, EncSze, CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
  begin
    Setlength(Result, j);
    Move(Enc, Result[1], EncSze);
  end;
end;

function WinMemDcr(EncInp: String): String;
var
  Enc: Pointer;
  j: Integer;
  EncSze: Cardinal;
  ws: String;
const
  CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS: Cardinal = 0;
begin
  j := Length(EncInp);
  EncSze := j * 2;
  ws := EncInp;
  Enc := Pointer(ws);
  if CryptUnprotectMemory(Enc, EncSze, CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
  begin
    Setlength(Result, j);
    Move(Enc, Result[1], EncSze);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Before you go on, you need to stop treating text and binary as interchangeable. You seem to think that a string is an array of bytes. It is not.

Comment: I do understand the difference and accept that the code is rough, test quality. However you have not explained how the difference affects the operating of the code.

Comment: You don't understand the difference. That is clear in the code. You pass text when you need to pass binary. Encryption works with binary data, you supply text. Encode the text as binary using a known encoding, and encrypt that.

Comment: I clearly do not understand why this does not work, but possibly not quite the way you mean.. I would be grateful if you explain why the following code works when the commented out line is active but not otherwise. Note that the pointer is still pointing at the string (and I am not using encoding as I am dealing with non textual info

Comment: `procedure ;
var
  Enc: Pointer;
  EncSze: Cardinal;
  ws: String;
  wb: TBytes;
const
  CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS: Cardinal = 0;
begin
  EncSze := 64;
  ws := '12345678901234567890123456789012';
  Setlength(wb, EncSze);
//  Move(ws[1], wb[0], 64);
  Enc := Pointer(ws);
  if CryptProtectMemory(Enc, EncSze, CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
  begin
    if CryptUnprotectMemory(Enc, EncSze, CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
    begin
      if (ws = '12345678901234567890123456789012') then
        showmessage('yes');
    end;
  end
  else showmessage(inttostr(GetLastError()));
end;
`

Comment: Sorry - I also dont know how to insert copde in comments

Comment: The big problem is that you are treating text as though it were binary. Encode the text as a byte arrayt using a known text encoding, and crypt the byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `EncryptionBlockSize := 8;` while in my library `CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE = 16`.
You also mistakenly move only half of the input string to ws, because `j` holds the length of the string while `Move()` moves `Count` number of *bytes*. A `Unicode` `Char` is 2 bytes.

As said in the comments, encryption/decryption works on bytes and storing an encryption in a string is a potential disaster.

So here's my suggestion for a encryption/decryption of a string with encrypted storage in TBytes.

```
function MemEncrypt(const StrInp: String): TBytes;
begin
  Result := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(StrInp);
  if Length(Result) mod CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE <> 0 then
    SetLength(Result, ((Length(Result) div CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE) + 1) * CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE);
  if not CryptProtectMemory(Result, Length(Result), CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message: '+IntToStr(GetLastError));
end;

function MemDecrypt(const EncInp: TBytes): String;
var
  EncTmp: TBytes;
begin
  EncTmp := Copy(EncInp);
  if CryptUnprotectMemory(EncTmp, Length(EncTmp), CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_SAME_PROCESS) then
    result := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(EncTmp)
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message: '+IntToStr(GetLastError));
end;
```

In the decryption a copy of the input TBytes is made to preserve the encrypted data.

And finally a test procedure:

```
procedure TForm13.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Txt = '1234567890123456789012345678901';
var
  s: string;
  b: TBytes;
begin
  s := Txt;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);

  b := MemEncrypt(Txt);

  s := MemDecrypt(b);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for that nice piece of code - I accepted this solution though as noted on HeartWare's reply I agree with him that the Move(Enc, is the basic cause of the problem.

Comment: UTF8 is usually a more efficient choice. Furthermore it avoids issues of endianness.

Comment: @BushAl Thanks, I didn't repeat HeartWare's finding but equally incorrect was your `Move(PlnTxt[1], ws[1], j);` as I pointed out moved only half of the input string.

Comment: @David Yes, I agree, and I didn't even think about the endianness. I need to catch up on that. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing it (purely from the looks of your code), I believe the problem lies in the MOVE statement:

```
Move(Enc, Result[1], EncSze);
```

You are moving data from the location of the pointer - not from the data that the pointer is pointing to.

You should use

```
Move(Enc^, Result[1], EncSze);
```

to move data from the location that is POINTED TO by the pointer, and not from the pointer itself.

To clarify: The Enc variable is - say - located at address $12345678 and the data you are manipulating is located at address $99999999

This means that at address $12345678 is located 4 bytes ($99 $99 $99 and $99). And at address $99999999 is located the data you are manipulating.

The statement

```
Move(Enc, Result[1], EncSze);
```

thus moves EncSize bytes from the address $12345678 to the 1st character of the string variable Result. This you do not want, as it will only move 4 bytes of $99 and then whatever follows at address $1234567C and on.

To move data from the address $99999999 you need to tell the compiler, that you want to move data from the location POINTED TO by the pointer, and not from the POINTER itself:

```
Move(Enc^, Result[1], EncSze);
```

But other that that, I agree with David. You should stop using strings as storage for non-string data. It'll bite you in the a** at some point. Use a byte array (TBytes) instead.

Comment: The asker has Unicode Delphi, with 16 bit strings. It's biting him in the a** already.

Comment: Thank you - I also (belately) think this is the root cause of the problem. However Tom below posted a full solution so I upvoted you and accepted his. David (and you and Tom) are correct in your comments on TBytes.

Comment: Sorry - I tried, but am told I need to get more reputation? - I'll make a note and try later.